# Powershell to move Excel files based on Initial part of the file name

Tags: powershell

I have hundreds of excel files like the following in directory called `D:\TestARC_Source`

```
5020190429.dat
5120190429.dat
602019111121.dat
702019050926.dat 
etc.
```

I need a script to move them to respective folders based on first two characters of file name. Folders are already created on target directory.

```
D:\TestARC_Destination\file_50
D:\TestARC_Destination\file_51
D:\TestARC_Destination\file_60
D:\TestARC_Destination\file_70
```

Files should move to respective folders based on first two characters of file name. For example `5020190429.dat` moves to `50_file` folder.

I am trying to edit below script but it's not working. I have a very little knowledge in PS script and I'll appreciate if you can help me out.

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ARC_Testing\TestARC_Source\"
$targetFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ARC_Testing\TestARC_Destination\"

# Find all files matching *.sql in the folder specified
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.dat | ForEach-Object {

    # Combine the source filename and target directory
    # The source filename has all instances of _ replaced with \
    # Cast the resulting string to a FileInfo object to take advantage of extra methods
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$destination = (Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath $_.Name.replace("_","\"))

    # Create the directory if it doesn't already exits
    if (!(Test-Path) $destination.Directory.FullName)
    { 
        New-item -Path $destination.Directory.FullName -ItemType Directory 
    }

    # Copy the source to the target directory
    copy-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination.FullName 
}
```

Comment: Your text and example  differ, is the scheme `file_50` or `50_file`? Also your title will move, while your code copies?

Comment: Hi.. Sorry for my wrong explanation. Actually folder names is 50_file NOT file_50. Same goes for others 53_file, 60_file and 70_file. Can we add one more functionality that if any other file comes up(like 14, 20 etc) and the folder is not available in destination, it should leave the file as it is in source folder. Thank You and sorry for the mess :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should move the files based on your criteria. Please remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are satisfied with what will be moved.

```
$Source = "D:\TestARC_Source"
$Dest = "D:\TestARC_Destination"

$FilesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File -Recurse -Filter "*.dat" -Include "[0-9][0-9]*"

Foreach ($file in $FilesToMove) {
    Move-Item -Path $file -Destination "$Dest\File_$($file.basename.substring(0,2))” -WhatIf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient approach would be to group the files by the 1st two digits,
check if the folder exists (and create if necessary) and move the files in one go.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\31\SO_56397901.ps1
$SourceFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ARC_Testing\TestARC_Source\"
$targetFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ARC_Testing\TestARC_Destination\"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$SourceFolder[0-9][0-9]*" -Filter *.dat | 
   Group-Object {"file_"+$_.BaseName.Substring(0,2)}| ForEach-Object {
      $TargetDir = Join-Path $targetFolder $_.Name
      if(!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){MD $TargetDir | Out-Null}
      $_.Group.FullName | Move-Item -Destination $TargetDir #-WhatIf
}
```

Tree after running with your above testdata:

```
> TREE /f
├───FILE_50
│       5020190429.DAT
│
├───FILE_51
│       5120190429.DAT
│
├───FILE_60
│       602019111121.DAT
│
└───FILE_70
        702019050926.DAT
```

**EDIT: Changing Requirements usually afford a new question, nevertheless the changes are minimal**

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\31\SO_56397901.ps1
$SourceFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ARC_Testing\TestARC_Source\"
$targetFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ARC_Testing\TestARC_Destination\"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$SourceFolder[0-9][0-9]*" -Filter *.dat | 
   Group-Object {$_.BaseName.Substring(0,2)+"_file"}| ForEach-Object {
      $TargetDir = Join-Path $targetFolder $_.Name
      if(Test-Path $TargetDir){
          $_.Group.FullName | Move-Item -Destination $TargetDir #-WhatIf
      } else {
          "{0} doesn't exist, files not moved: {1}" -f $TargetDir,($_.Group.FullName -join ';')
      } 
}
```

Comment: See changed answer. Hint for a new contributor: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)✔ and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (once you've got a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of 15 it will be seen)